# Highlight Items from created listbox (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

For a few weeks I've been busy creating a program for the Dutch railroads.

Using Tkinter and Python I've managed to monitor all trains driving and all trainfailures.

At the moment I'm having a problem monitoring the trainfailures. I made a button that says: 'Laad storing' (or: Load all failures). This button then uses an API to create a Listbox.

After that I would like to search the Listbox for certain values (Like 'Station Amsterdam, or Station Utrecht). I would like to have this certain value highlighted. (So and CTRL+F sort of function).

Anyone who could help me?

Here is my code creating the listbox:

```
def bevestigen_storingen():
actuele_storingen = 'http://webservices.ns.nl/ns-api-storingen?station=&actual=true&unplanned=true'
response_storing = requests.get(actuele_storingen, auth=login_api)
storingXML = xmltodict.parse(response_storing.text)
listbox_storing.delete(0, 'end')
storingenInvoer_autocomplete.configure(highlightbackground='#00339E', highlightthickness=0)
try:
    for vertrek in storingXML['Storingen']['Gepland']['Storing']:
        traject = vertrek['Traject']
        bericht = vertrek['Bericht']
        bb = re.sub("<p>|</p>|<b>|</b>|<br/>|<br/>u", "", bericht)
        aa = re.split("Wanneer: |Oorzaak: |Advies: |Extra reistijd: ", bb)
        listbox_storing.insert(END, "Traject: {}".format(traject))
        listbox_storing.insert(END, "Wanneer: {}".format(aa[1]))
        listbox_storing.insert(END, "Oorzaak: {}".format(aa[2]))
        listbox_storing.insert(END, "Advies: {}".format(aa[3]))
        listbox_storing.insert(END, "Extra reistijd: {}".format(aa[4]), "\n")
except:
    storingenInvoer_autocomplete.configure(highlightbackground='#00339E', highlightthickness=3, highlightcolor="red")
```

Answer (score 0):

The listbox is a widget that contains a list of strings, so I'd search it the way I'd search a list of strings. The methods are a bit different but that should not be a problem.

I'm not clear wether you want to highlight single words or the whole line. As far as I've been able to understand you can only select one or several entire lines.

Have a look at [The Tkinter Listbox Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm)